# Question about mapDispatchToProps and bindActionCreators when multipla actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, mapdispatchtoprops

I learn React Redux and reading [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) about using `mapDispatchToProps` and `bindActionCreators`

It works fine the `bindActionCreators` when using it alone like so:

```
export default connect(null, (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(FormContainer);
```

But I have more actions and tried this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch),
    clearPosts: () => dispatch(clearPosts()),
  }
}
```

And that gives error like so:

[image]

. How can I combine them I read the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) and there's nothing as I can see about this please advice

Comment: You would need ... before bindActionCreators but you don’t need to use bindActionCreators inside mapDispatchToProps as connect binds them for you. You can just do ...actionCreators instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
 function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        todoActions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch),
        clearPosts: () => dispatch(clearPosts()),
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to use the "map object" notation nowadays **if you really want to use `connect`**.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    ...actionCreators,
    clearPosts
}
```

But also, the recommendation is [to use redux hooks instead of connect](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api) if you can use function components, as they are generally easier to use.

(If you were following a tutorial that was showing you `connect`, it might be outdated, please see the [official redux tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index) instead)